Supplier's Products and Internal Products - Separate Product Tables?
I'm building an ERP system where we can import our suppliers' product data before purchasing their products. Under the current design, supplier products are stored in a separate table and when we decide to purchase a product we import the product information into an internal product table, linking the two entries so changes are synchronized. Before continuing further down this path, I'd like your feedback on if you think this two-table approach is better than using a single table.
Separate Table Pros and Cons
Pros

Keeps our internal products table clean, and only adds the products that we are going to use
More normalized in that internal products have more fields, settings, and connections to other tables in the system (such as Purchase Receipt, Stock Entries, Work Order, Sales Order) that aren't necessary for supplier products

Cons

Consolidated reporting on supplier and internal product stock levels requires merging two tables
End up with a lot of duplicate product data on the two tables

Single Table Pros and Cons
Pros

Easy to use a Supplier / Internal product identifier to separate the two types
Consolidated supplier and internal reporting and filtering is simpler off a single table

Cons

The product table used internally will be filled with many products we may never buy/use
Supplier products don't need most of the fields and connections that internal products need

I'm leaning towards maintaining two tables, but I'm new to databases so if you have thoughts on this based on your experience and knowledge I would greatly appreciate it.

No add a column that indicates what type it is, so you can easy filter it, when you put it in an combined index

To clarify, are you advocating for separate tables, and then combining them?

@nbk What Thomas is describing are two Inventory type tables. One is company owned, the other sounds like consignment. They should remain as separate tables, as is industry standard.

I'd prefer single table. The product table used internally will be filled with many products we may never buy/use - partitioned by the product type. Supplier products don't need most of the fields and connections that internal products need Sparse table is not a problem.

@Akina I think you're missing the same business logical points as nbk. Supplier Products are a different type of object than Company Owned Products. The Supplier can modify the Supplier Products in ways that don't make sense relative to Company Owned Products. For example, nothing stops the Supplier from moving a particular Product of theirs out of the Location reserved for OP's Company and putting it into a different Location reserved for a completely different and unrelated Company to OP's, traditionally speaking.
